# springboot hibernate exception entity is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to unit test my service classes in a spring-hibernate application.

```
public class UserServiceTest extends SpringAwareTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    private UserService userSvc;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("roleService")
    private RoleService roleSvc;

    ...

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/application-test-context.xml")
@Transactional
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@Configurable
public abstract class BaseSpringAwareTest {
   ....
}
```

My spring context file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
    >

    <!-- import resource="classpath:/applicationContext.xml"/ -->
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.olp"/>
    
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.olp.jpa"  entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitMgr"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="persistenceUnitMgr" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence-test.xml"/>
        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="productHubTest"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                <value>com.olp.jpa</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    
...
    
</beans>
```

I am getting this exception while executing the JUnits -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserEntity is not
> mapped [SELECT t FROM UserEntity t  JOIN FETCH t.roles   ORDER BY
> t.userName ASC]   at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:713)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ...

**My entity classes are in child packages of the top level component scan mentioned - "com.olp"**

```
package com.olp.jpa.domain.docu.um.model;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "trl_users")
@Cacheable(true)
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(....)
})
// ... 
public class UserEntity extends MultiTenantLifeCycleEntity {
// ...
}


package com.olp.jpa.common;
@MappedSuperclass
public class MultiTenantLifeCycleEntity {
   // ...
}
```

Couldn't identify the root cause. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your project through github so that I can solve the issue ?

Comment: @AnishB.   , thanks for responding. It would be difficult for me to share the project. If you can suggest anything I can try it out.

Comment: Why are you going for xml based approach in spring-boot application?

Comment: @AnishB. , in the past i ran into issues with hibernate ogm integration using java configuration , hence had to switch to xml config

Comment: Try (1) putting `persistence-test.xml` in a `META-INF` directory, (2) setting `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` to `false` inside the file. BTW `@Configurable` is redundant on a Spring Boot test

Comment: @crizzis , thanks. I'll try your suggestions